# C# AssemblyVersion : how is it managed automatically

Tags: c#, version

As we know, the following code manage build number and revision automatically.
(As I know, AssemblyVersion is "major.minor.build_number.revision")

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.5.*")]
```

By the way, How does it deal with build number and revision? In my case, the version start from `2.5.5155.32464` and revision increase some at each build, and sometimes build number increase, too. But I can't find any rule of increments....

Comment: @m.edmondson No. What I say is NOT how to increase, but how is increment managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article explains it the best:-

> Build Number component – Number of days since the year 2000.
>
> Revision component – Number of seconds since midnight divided by 2 and yes this
> number is not random as stated by MSDN.

[Original Article](http://www.jsinh.in/2013/09/how-to-auto-increment-version-number-of-assembly-in-dotnet-csharp/)

Comment: I'm surprised at that.. it is just time?